# How do I define a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
is the error I get with the following reader method:

```
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> getReader(DataSource datasource, String query, String name) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(datasource)
                .sql(query)
                .name(name)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
```

Where the step config looks like :

```
public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                         DataSource dataSource,
                         ItemReader reader,
                         ExpireAssessmentWriter writer, //use custom writer
                         AssessmentItemProcessor processor,
                         PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(getReader(dataSource, READER_QUERY, "AssessmentReader"))
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

Why am i getting an error when trying to pass a string to getReader?

EDIT:
The error comes from the second parameter in getReader. I am just trying to pass the query as a string but the Error output looks like:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method getReader in com.batch.config.ExpirationUtilityConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting, including a stack trace?

Comment: What do you mean "a bean of type String?"  The only bean I see is of type `JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment>`.  That bean's factory function takes a String as a parameter, but that parameter isn't a bean.

Comment: That's what the error states when I try to pass "String query" param to getReader method. I edited the post above to reflect @Steve

Comment: Ok.  Never seen that particular type of error message before.  I think the error message must be misleading because it doesn't make sense to define a bean of type String so that you can look for that bean by its type.  Do you have a stack trace for the error?  Are you sure that the call you show to `getReader` is where the problem is?  I ask because from what I see, that call should having nothing to do with Spring beans...it's just a normal Java method call.

Comment: There is no stack trace from what I see. What I put as the error output is all it shows after **APPLICATION FAILED TO START**

and as far as I can tell, the error is stemming from the getReader call...since the error states the parameter passed to getReader is not found although not entirely sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `@Bean` on `getReader()`. Since you are calling `getReader` in your step definition, you don't need to declare the reader as a Spring bean.

You need to remove the ItemReader from the parameters list of your step definition as well.

Comment: Hi again Mahmoud, thanks for responding here. 
If I remove @Bean from getReader() the the error shows :
Parameter 2 of method step1 in com.usaa.batch.config.ExpirationUtilityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' in your configuration.

Comment: you need to remove it from the parameters list in the step definition, otherwise Spring will look for a bean of type ItemReader and there is no one since you `@Bean` has been removed. I updated the answer accordingly. As a side note, you should not duplicate questions (or similar questions) like this as it is not efficient to answer in different places and cross reference things. Anyway, if the answer helped, please accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the kind responses Mahmoud. Removing the ItemReader from the param list and removing @Bean made it work. 

Really appreciate your time.