# Why can't I pass a String param to this method without Spring complaining about a Bean

Tags: spring, spring-batch

The question is quite simple really but I can't figure out why Spring is complaining.

I want to be able to pass a different query to the ItemReader in each step but Spring complains about the parameter in the getReader method:

```
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> getReader(DataSource datasource, String query, String name) {
        return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment>()
                .dataSource(datasource)
                .sql(query)
                .name(name)
                .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
                .build();
    }
```

And the step config would look like this:

```
@Bean
    public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory factory,
                         DataSource dataSource,
                         ItemReader reader,
                         ExpireAssessmentWriter writer, //use custom writer
                         AssessmentItemProcessor processor,
                         PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .<Assessment,Assessment>chunk(10)
                .reader(getReader(dataSource, READER_QUERY, "AssessmentReader
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

Where I have READER_QUERY as a variable.
Application fails to start with below output:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method reader in com.batch.config.ExpirationUtilityConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

If I remove the @Bean annotation from getReader() then I get a similar output stating:

```
Description:

Parameter 2 of method step1 in com.batch.config.ExpirationUtilityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader' in your configuration.
```

Not really understanding what is going on here... I am just trying to pass a String to getReader() ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I define a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in Spring Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64127723/how-do-i-define-a-bean-of-type-java-lang-string-in-spring-batch)

Comment: It does, thanks MAhmoud

Answer (score 1):

## Your problem in a nutshell

It's simple, you have a bean (**JdbcCursorItemReader**) which requires two String arguments:

```
String query, String name
```

But Spring doesn't find them in the context. Every argument that **ANY** bean requires **has to be defined somewhere** in a parent/child context/config.

Where do you expect query and name are coming from? Are they coming from property files, how are they defined?

## Learning about properties + property files

In any case, let's say you defined them into a property file which has this content:

```
queryConfig.query=SELECT * from whatever;
queryConfig.queryName=someQueryName
```

Alternatively, you can define these props in a **yaml** file, pass them as environmental variables or whatever you like, please take a look at the following link to see what Spring has to offer: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

## What to do AFTER you have chosen a propertySource

Anyway, once you have the query and queryName defined in some way, it's time to start using them in your app. First thing to know, it's not a good practice to have String parameters flying around, so you'd probably go about bundling these two props in a Configuration object on their own, or at least in a class e.g:

```
public class QueryProperties {
    private String query;
    private String queryName;
    //...getters, setters and constructor (I usually use lombok so this is boilerplate for me)
}
```

and then ExpirationUtilityConfig should look something like:

```
  @Configuration
  public class ExpirationUtilityConfig {
      /**
      * This is one of the ways to get the value of a property which is defined in a propertySource 
      */
      @Value("${queryConfig.query}") private String query;
      @Value("${queryConfig.queryName}") private String queryName;

      /**
       * This will make sure you got a QueryPropeties object in your Spring config, which can be used (injected in) by the JdbcCursorItemReader below
       */
      @Bean
      public QueryProperties getQueryProperties() {
          return new QueryProperties(query, queryName);
      }

      @Bean
      public JdbcCursorItemReader<Assessment> getReader(DataSource datasource, QueryProperties queryProperties) {
          return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Assessment> ()
              .dataSource(datasource)
              .sql(queryProperties.getQuery()) // use the queryPropeties.getQuery() or simply query from @Value
              .name(queryProperties.getQueryName())
              .rowMapper(new AssessmentMapper())
              .build();
      }

      @Bean
      public Step step1(StepBuilderFactory factory,
          DataSource dataSource,
          ItemReader reader,
          ExpireAssessmentWriter writer, //use custom writer
          AssessmentItemProcessor processor,
          PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
          return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
              .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
              .<Assessment, Assessment> chunk(10)
              .reader(getReader(dataSource, READER_QUERY, "AssessmentReader")
                  .processor(processor)
                  .writer(writer)
                  .build()
              ));
      }
  }
```